# Manual trigger reserved to specific branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow on one of my repo which can apply or revert DB migrations. I want to be able to trigger it manually but I want to keep it only for main branch.

Here head of my workflow file:

```
name: up
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  ...
```

Comment: Assuming you need credentials for that, you can expose them via an [environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) only accessible to the right branch. Or just run the job conditionally on which branch is active: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif. You can't stop the workflow being triggered on other branches, but you can make it not matter if it is.

Comment: oh well good idea ! you're a genious ! will test it asap

Comment: thanks for the edit too, last sentence was only here to be polite. I know that SO removes automatically polite sentences but my mother taught me to always be polite.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being polite, but context matters. Doing something you know is discouraged, causing work for other people, isn't polite.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this practice to don't allow to say hello and thanks, it's basis of any society.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `if` that checks for the branch / github ref to the job configuration:

```yaml
name: up
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  my-job:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      - ...
```

Replace `main` with the branch you want to limit the job to.

Be aware that you have to add the `if:` for every job if you use multiple jobs.